# JavaFX - using toggle isSelected() in conditional statements

Tags: if-statement, netbeans, radio-button, toggle, javafx-8

I'm building a simple sketch program using JavaFX. I want the user to be able to switch between drawing a rectangle, circle or line and I've put toggle radio buttons in the menu for these options.

Is it possible to write an if/else statement so I can write code for three different functions depending on which is selected? At the moment it will only draw lines. This is part of my code so far (sorry it's messy):

```
package Sketchbook;



public class Sketchbook extends Application {

final static int CANVAS_WIDTH = 800;
final static int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;

ColorPicker colorPicker1;
ColorPicker colorPicker2;


@Override

public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
final GraphicsContext graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
initDraw(graphicsContext);

canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, 
new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
graphicsContext.beginPath();
graphicsContext.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
graphicsContext.setStroke(colorPicker1.getValue());
graphicsContext.stroke();
}
});

canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, 
new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
graphicsContext.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
graphicsContext.setStroke(colorPicker1.getValue());
graphicsContext.stroke();
}
});

canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, 
new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

}
});       

Group root = new Group();

ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
RadioButton rectangle = new RadioButton("Rectangle");
RadioButton circle = new RadioButton("Circle");
RadioButton line = new RadioButton("Line");
rectangle.setSelected(true);
rectangle.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
circle.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
line.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much already described what you need to do:

```
canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, 

    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle() == line) {
                graphicsContext.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                graphicsContext.setStroke(colorPicker1.getValue());
                graphicsContext.stroke();
            } else if (toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle() == rectangle) {
                // etc...
            } // etc...

        }
    }
});
```

Obviously you may need to reorder the code a little to make sure variables are declared and initialized before you use them.

Comment: Thank you so much - I think I was overthinking it! All working now.